# Are variables de-allocated when they go out of scope

Tags: scala

Given this code snippet

```
def doSomething() = {

    val associations : HashMap[Int, Int] = function_that_create_a_hashmap
    println("something")
}
```

When `doSomething` terminates is the variable `associations` de-allocated? Should I call some destructor on it (maybe `.clear`, in this case) or is that operation not useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.clear` on a `HashMap` doesn't remove it from memory; it simply clears it of preexisting mappings and so the object will still exist in memory.

Since Scala runs on the JVM, I would imagine that it will get collected by the garbage collector at some point in the future (assuming that there are no existing-references to `associations`). The JVM manages its own memory, thus freeing the programmer of the burden of manually-managing memory.

Answer (score 7):

That is not necessary - if your application has no more references to the `HashMap`, then it will be garbage collected automatically at some point in the future.

If you really have a huge hash map that you want to get rid off to avoid its memory consumption trigger GC cycles after `doSomething` completes, you can call `System.gc()`, but this is in general neither needed nor a recommended practice.

Comment: In fact calls to System.gc() doesn't give you any guarantee of the GC being called. It's taken as a suggestion from the JVM implementation, which could even totally ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The binding `associations` ceases to exist when the scope in which it was created ceases to exist (when a given call to `doSomething` returns). That removes one reference to the `HashMap` and once there are none left, the value is garbage and subject to reclamation at an unspecified time in the future (possibly never / not before the JVM exits).